# getting highest values in a data set

Tags: php, mysql

I am taking gps data and drawing a map, I would like to show the maximum speed at various points. I would need to keep track of the speed value for each data point and if it decreases mark the previous point as a max value.

Is this something i could do nicely in MySql, or do I just loop though it in php and get the values. It is quite simple to do via php, but includes pulling out loads of data that is not really required.

One data set could be up to 20k rows give or take a few thousand.

From the graph below I would expect 4 data points back. Table structure is simple id, long, lat, speed (not that it matters much)

EDIT:
id is a uuid, not integer :/

[image: badly drawn example data]

Comment: obvious question: how are you drawing the map without PHP touching all the data points? In other words: aren't you already iterating through the full dataset in order to plot the data?

Comment: I say keep at lest the last two points in memory. So, always write one point behind.

Comment: valid point, but why loop through 15k rows doing all sorts of comparisons when there could be maybe 50 high points. In my case its a map of a race track so there is almost 1 high point per corner, and a track has 10 -> 20 corners. very small compared to the total data points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have ids > 0:

```
SELECT id, speed FROM (
  SELECT
    if(speed<@speed,@id,0) AS id,
    if(speed<@speed,@id:=0,@id:=id) AS ignoreme,
    @speed:=speed AS speed
  FROM
    (SELECT @speed:=0) AS initspeed,
    (SELECT @id:=0) AS initid,
    yourtable
  WHERE ...
) AS baseview
WHERE id>0
```

This will compare the last speed with the current speed, give the last rising id and speed for every falling interval, 0 and the speed for all other cases in the inner query. From that we select only those rows, that have a positive id

Comment: seem like the right way to go, but I can not get that to work. mysql complains about the part after your FROM. "(@speed:=0) AS initspeed"

Comment: It is now returning data, will run some more tests to make sure its 100% correct, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this one and it works just fine. Not sure if it will have increased performance over PHP, but most likely will. It creates two "temp selects" and joins them by rownum (it would be good if you can sort those selects by something, just to be sure that you will get the same order, I'm ordering by id), and then it makes a join, but by shifting second table by 1...that way A.speed - B.speed gives difference between "current" and "previous" value. At the end, you just need records where that difference is > 0...Hope this helps.

```
SELECT A.speed, A.speed - B.speed as diff
FROM 
    (SELECT @rownumA:=@rownumA+1 AS rownum, speed
    FROM speed_table ORDER BY id,
    (SELECT @rownumA:=0) r) A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT @rownumB:=@rownumB+1 AS rownum, speed
    FROM speed_table ORDER BY id,
    (SELECT @rownumB:=0) r) B ON A.rownum = B.rownum - 1
WHERE A.speed - B.speed > 0
```

Comment: what exactly is this part ment to be doing? (SELECT @rownumA:=0) r) A. mysql barfs on that.

Comment: That part creates rownumA variable and sets its value to 0 and then you select from that "table". You can achieve the same thing without that part, but specifying SET @rownumA = 0; at the top.